# iText7 Field Event Action not working

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext, itext7

Trying to find documentation on the actions but there is very little.

Looking through their [api](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.1/) tells me little about any of the fields of the PdfName class.

I found a snippet of code [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/actions-and-annotations/itext7-how-add-onmouseover-javascript-action-textfield) that briefly goes over the PdfName field values V, E, X, D, and U.

However, these field values do not set up the events correctly.

When I create a signature field and then add actions in the following code, only the V event fires, none of the other events.

```
PdfSignatureFormField sigField = PdfFormField.createSignature(pdf);             
sigField.setFieldName("signature");

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.V, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
    "app.alert(\"Validation\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.E, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
    "app.alert(\"Mouse Enter\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.X, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
    "app.alert(\"Mouse Exit\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.D, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
    "app.alert(\"Mouse Down\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.U, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
    "app.alert(\"Mouse Up\")"));
```

Does anyone know why the events aren't firing properly?

Comment: Regarding PdfName, please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17645840/766786

Comment: 1) What viewer are you using to open the pdf? iText  doesn't validate or execute the js, it's the viewer that's supposed to implement the JS parser.
2) The PdfName fields are mostly straight implementation from the pdf-names for dictionary entries, and those are found in the Pdf-spec (ISO-32000)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your code how you relate widgets with your form field.

You can use `createSignature(PdfDocument, Rectangle)` method to specify the widget annotation rectangle right away. There are other ways to add widgets to the form field later, but again, it is not clear from your code whether you are doing it or not.

In any case, following is a completely working piece of code producing the file for which events are correctly firing in Adobe Reader (and even in the default Windows Pdf Reader).

```
PdfFormField sigField = PdfFormField.createSignature(doc, new Rectangle(72, 632, 200, 100));
sigField.setFieldName("signature");
sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.V, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
        "app.alert(\"Validation\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.E, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
        "app.alert(\"Mouse Enter\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.X, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
        "app.alert(\"Mouse Exit\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.D, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
        "app.alert(\"Mouse Down\")"));

sigField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.U, PdfAction.createJavaScript(
        "app.alert(\"Mouse Up\")"));
form.addField(sigField);
```